# How to use lightbox to display PHP query results from an SQL server after submitting form criteria

Tags: php, sql, forms, lightbox

So I'm redesigning the intranet for the library of a county-based historical society, and they have ridiculous amounts of data.  Since the tables returning the data are so huge, every method I've tried to use so far breaks the layout and looks ugly.  I'm hoping that some kind of lightbox feature could help display tabular data results.

Basically I want this form:

```
<form action="proc_church.php" method=post name=query>
    <br>
    <span style="color: #fff;">Input a <b>surname </b>&nbsp;</span>
    <select name="sname">
      <option selected value="Last_Name">Last Name</option>
      <option value="Maiden_Name">Maiden Name</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;
    <input type=text name=surname size=30>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span style="color: #fff;">Input a first name&nbsp;</span>
    <input type=text name=firstname size=30>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span style="color: #fff;">Sort By&nbsp;</span>
    <select name=pick>
      <option value="First_Name">First Name</option>
      <option value="Last_Name, First_Name">Last Name, then first name</option>
      <option value="[Church References].Church_Reference">Church</option>
      <option value="Page">Page</option>
      <option value="Exact_or_Range_Start_Date">Start Date</option>
      <option value="Range_End_Date">End Date</option>
    </select>
    <input type=hidden name=orders>
    <input type=button value="Submit Query" onClick="process()" id=sub>
  </form>
```

to splash to a lightbox pop-up of the `proc_church.php` page seen in the code.

If anyone could tell me which lightbox plugin would do this easiest (and how to execute it) or if it's even possible I'd really appreciate it.  If it's not possible I'd love a few suggestions on how to accomplish it, like maybe a js pop-up window. Thanks.

Comment: technically, lightbox **IS** a "js pop-up windows".

Comment: Well I meant just like a basic "open in new window" kind of thing, if I can't get it to work with lightbox